# Global Feathers hooks and event filters

Tags: feathersjs

In Express, it's very easy to block access to all routes starting, say, with the `/admin` prefix, simply by adding a middleware to that path before adding handlers for any specific endpoints under that path.

In Feathers, it looks like we have to create some common hook modules and add them to every service we created, individually. Same goes for event filters.

I find the thought of forgetting to add an authentication hook or event filter scary, because I wouldn't notice the mistake unless I reviewed all service initialization code or got hacked. In that sense, an Express middleware with some sort of white-listing I can easily implement for exceptional endpoints gives me much more peace of mind.

Is it possible to do something like that in Feathers?

(P.S.: I just noticed I had protected my app's REST API, but had forgotten to protect all real-time events).

Answer (score 3):

As of v1.6.0 `feathers-hooks` supports application hooks that run on all services via `app.hooks`:

```
app.hooks({
  before(hook) {
    console.log('Global before hook');
  },

  after(hook) {
    console.log('Global after hook');
  },

  error(hook) {
    console.error(`Error in ${hook.path} method ${hook.method}`, hook.error.stack);
  }
});
```

For more examples see [this blog post about error and application hooks](https://blog.feathersjs.com/feathers-application-and-error-hooks-7a5982e70024#.r5h2q7stq).

As for the real-time events, [channels](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html) are used which provide a safe way to send events only to the clients that should see them.

Comment: is app.hooks still available for v2.0.3? I tried but it seems not work.

Comment: I tent to add authorization for all services, `auth.hooks.restrictToAuthenticated()`